# Django is not running. Django not found error occurs

Tags: python, django, frameworks

python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

`import django  django.__file__ /Users/dc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/__init__.py`

django  also works

I installed Django from pip3 in Mac m1 but it is not running
`your text`

Comment: Please format the text in your question and add the exact error message.